# I am finding [none] in the drop down of Android virtual device, on the device chooser

Tags: android, android-emulator

I'm new to android studio, and my tutorial tells me that when i run i get to choose nexas 5, API 21 x86, under the android device chooser drop down list
but it the list is empty and it lists [none], showing that there is no default emulator a Nexus 5 running KitKat. any suggestions?

Comment: You must to create first android virtual device check this link http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Creating_an_Android_Virtual_Device_%28AVD%29_in_Android_Studio

Comment: @g2o thanks a lot, it has helped.